# Different between return a list and a tuple in python

Tags: python

What is the Different between return a list and a tuple in python ?
for example:

```
def func1(a,b):
  return a,b

def func2(a,b):
  return [a,b]
```

When I can use func1 and when I can use func2 ?

Comment: They are conceptually different entities, see duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1):

One return value will be a list and the other will be a tuple. You can use either whenever you like provided you understand what it means to use a list instead of a tuple and vice versa.